# How to correctly go on medical leave and claim Employment Insurance due to workplace conditions

Tags: stress, canada, leave-of-absence

For the last year and a half I have been daily stressed at my current workplace,
and I don't think I can take it anymore.

It's just piled up from the amount of responsibilities I have, my boss's inability to acknowledge my workload and questioning my every decision without alternative suggestions.

I need a few weeks off to heal and return to be myself again.

In my field, it can take some time to land a different job.
Also its tightly packed, so any movement on my part would go back to the boss.

What is the correct procedure to finish my current work and go to medical leave with Employment Insurance? Would need few months tops.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere It is not clear if he has consulted a doctor. So before taking any actions, discuss every symptom you have with your doctor. Ask his personal opinion, but I think only rare cases will lead to more than 2 weeks of rest. It may depend on your doctor, country and mental/physical state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The first step would be to visit your own doctor and explain the situation to him and seek to obtain a medical certificate.

Do this in conjunction with reading up on the information that Joe refers to in his comment above to make sure you understand the process and what you need to provide in order to claim your insurance.

> When you apply for sickness benefits, **you must also obtain a medical certificate signed by your doctor which indicates the expected period of incapacity**. Be sure to keep this certificate in a safe place, since we may ask you to provide it to us later. We will let you know if we need you to submit your medical certificate when you complete your online application.

[Source - Applying for Employment Insurance](https://www.canada.ca/en/services/benefits/ei/ei-sickness/before-applying.html) (Emphasis mine)